# git: 'flow' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: git, git-flow

I just tried to install git-flow, however, it does not seem to be integrated properly with git, what can I do to integrate gitflow with git? is there a way I can do this manually?

Thank you,
Jeffrey

```
[root@sa 2]# wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/raw/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh | sudo bash
### gitflow no-make installer ###
Installing git-flow to /usr/local/bin
Cloning repo from GitHub to gitflow
Cloning into gitflow...
remote: Counting objects: 2362, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (957/957), done.
remote: Total 2362 (delta 1406), reused 2238 (delta 1316)
Receiving objects: 100% (2362/2362), 484.60 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1406/1406), done.
Updating submodules
Submodule 'shFlags' (git://github.com/nvie/shFlags.git) registered for path 'shFlags'
Cloning into shFlags...
remote: Counting objects: 454, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (454/454), 101.19 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (389/389), done.
remote: Total 454 (delta 389), reused 454 (delta 389)
Submodule path 'shFlags': checked out '2fb06af13de884e9680f14a00c82e52a67c867f1'
removed `/usr/local/bin/git-flow'
`gitflow/git-flow' -> `/usr/local/bin/git-flow'
removed `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-init'
`gitflow/git-flow-init' -> `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-init'
removed `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-feature'
`gitflow/git-flow-feature' -> `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-feature'
removed `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-hotfix'
`gitflow/git-flow-hotfix' -> `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-hotfix'
removed `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-release'
`gitflow/git-flow-release' -> `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-release'
removed `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-support'
`gitflow/git-flow-support' -> `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-support'
removed `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-version'
`gitflow/git-flow-version' -> `/usr/local/bin/git-flow-version'
removed `/usr/local/bin/gitflow-common'
`gitflow/gitflow-common' -> `/usr/local/bin/gitflow-common'
removed `/usr/local/bin/gitflow-shFlags'
`gitflow/gitflow-shFlags' -> `/usr/local/bin/gitflow-shFlags'
[root@sa 2]# git flow
git: 'flow' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
        reflog
        show
```

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` on your path? Try running `which git-flow`, if `/usr/local/bin/git-flow` isn't found then you may need to modify your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, most likely `/usr/local/bin` isn't set in `$PATH`. Check it by doing `echo $PATH`, and if it doesn't show `/usr/local/bin`, add it to `$PATH`.

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: which git-flow give me "/usr/local/bin/git-flow"

Comment: echo $PATH give me "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"

Answer (score 10):

Remove git-flow and install it manually.

**On Linux:**

```
sudo apt-get remove git-flow && wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://raw.github.com/nvie/gitflow/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh | sudo bash
```

**On Windows**

If you work with cygwin make sure util-linux and wget are installed. Then run this with cygwin:

```
wget -q -O - --no-check-certificate github.com/nvie/gitflow/raw/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh | bash
```

For further information check the [project page on github](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Linux)

Comment: What about for windows?

Comment: @behelit I've updated my answer with instructions for windows

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on Windows 10 (SourceTree).
I added following folder to PATH variable in "Environment variables for user"

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\usr\bin
```

I closed and reopened the SourceTree - and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

on Ubuntu it just needs to get installed

```
sudo apt-get install -y git-flow
```

then `git flow`  commands will run OK  ...  other answer mentioning PATH is obsolete as git-flow it not a standalone executable its used internally by git directly